# Understanding the proof of the integral test.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I refer to [this proof](http://planetmath.org/proofofintegraltest) of the integral test.

I don't understand why $\int_{M+1}^{\infty}{g(x) dx}\leq \int_{M}^\infty {f(x) dx}$.

The descriptions of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are given in the link.

On sketching both, I can't form a clear conception of which is greater, as both exceed $\int_{M+1}^\infty {f(x) dx}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make your post self-content?

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is non-increasing (by premise), and

$$g(x) = a_{\lfloor x\rfloor} = f(\lfloor x\rfloor),$$

we have, by the fact $x < \lfloor x\rfloor + 1 = \lfloor x+1\rfloor$,

$$g(x+1) = f(\lfloor x+1\rfloor) \leqslant f(x),$$

and hence

$$\int_{M+1}^\infty g(x)\,dx = \int_M^\infty g(x+1)\,dx \leqslant \int_M^\infty f(x)\,dx.$$